# Lateral Flatten Snowpipe data with mixture of arrays and dict

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral, snowflake-task

I have two different structured json files being piped in from a snowpipe. The only difference is that instead of a nested dict it has many nested arrays. I am trying to figure out how to transform **structure 1** into one finalized table. I've successfully transformed **structure 2** into a table and included the code below.

I know I need to be making use of lateral flatten but have not been successful.

```
**Structure 1: Nested Arrays (Need help on)**
This json lives within a table and in column **JSONTEXT**
[
  {
    "ID": "xxx-xxxx-xxxx xxx-xxx",
    "caseTypeID": "xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
    "content": {
      "AccountID": "xx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx xxxx-xxxxx",
      "AccountName": "XXXX",
      "Address": {
        "pxObjClass": "Data-Address-Postal"
      },
      "Addresses": [],
      "AllKickoffsComplete": "true",
      "BillingContactList": [],
      "ClientCurrency": "USD",
      "ClientID": "XXXXXX",
      "ClientNSID": "XXXXXXXX-00",
      "ClientName": "XXXXX XXXX Inc.",
      "CompanyPhoneNumber": "XXX-XXX-XXXX",
      "CrmSearchOrg": "XXXX",
      "EEList": [
        {
          "AccountID": "xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx xxxx-xxxxx",
          "AccountName": "XXXX",
          "AllowanceList": [
            {
              "AllowanceAmount": "327",
              "AllowanceName": "Car Allowance",
              "pxObjClass": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
]
```

**Structure 2: Nested Dict**
This json lives within a table and in column **JSONTEXT**

```
[
  {
    "OppID": "xxxx-xxxxx",
    "pxObjClass": "xx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
    "pxPages": {
      "EEList": {
        "Country": "xxx",
        "CountryName": "xxx",
        "Currency": "xxx",
        "EstimatedICPCost": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ICPCurrency": "xxxxx",
        "ICPID": "xxxxxxxxx.",
        "ICPNSID": "xxxx-xx",
        "ICPName": "xxx xx xx.",
        "LocalMonthlySalary": "xxxxxx",
        "MinFee": "xxxx",
        "MonthlyGrossCost": "xxxxx",
        "NewOrRepeatCustomer": "xxxxx",
        "OppCloseDate": "xxx-xxx-xx",
        "OppID": "xxx-xxxx",
        "OpportunityName": "xxx - xxx xxx - xxx - xxxx",
        "ReferralSource": "xxxxxx",
        "pxObjClass": "Index-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx",
        "pxSubscript": "EEList"
      }
    },
    "pyID": "xxxxxx",
    "pzInsKey": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx xxxxx-xxx"
  },
]
```

Here is my code for the second structure that works.

```
create or replace table xxxx
    as select 
    value:ID::varchar as ID,
    value:caseTypeID::varchar as caseTypeID,
    value:content:AccountID::varchar as AccountID,
    value:content:AccountName::varchar as AccountName,
    value:content:AllKickoffsComplete::boolean as AllKickoffsComplete,
    value:content:ClientCurrency::varchar as ClientCurrency,
    value:content:ClientID::varchar as ClientID,
    value:content:ClientNSID::varchar as ClientNSID,
    value:content:ClientName::varchar as ClientName,
    value:content:CompanyAddressCountryName::varchar as CompanyAddressCountryName,
    value:content:CompanyPhoneNumber::varchar as CompanyPhoneNumber,
    value:content:CreateNew::boolean as CreateNew,
    value:content:CrmSearchOrg::varchar as CrmSearchOrg,
    value:content:EEList:AccountID::varchar as EE_AccountID,
    value:content:EEList:AccountName::varchar as EE_AccountName
from new_raw_json, 
    lateral flatten (input =>jsontext);
```

Here is code I've tried it only works when you put jsontext[Nth].

```
select
    value:ID::varchar as ID,
    value:EEListID::varchar as EEListID,
    value:caseTypeID::varchar as caseTypeID
    from new_raw_json,

    lateral flatten (input => jsontext[0]:content:EEList);
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I think the main problem is in row one of my table is actually a list not just a raw json. I am trying in python to reconstruct how the data is coming over!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [chain multiple lateral views using FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html#examples) to continue exploding into nested structures (arrays within arrays).

An explicitly defined approach may appear this way (only some columns are projected here, to illustrate levels):

```sql
SELECT
  outer_object.value:caseTypeID AS caseTypeID,
  outer_object.value:content.AccountID AS parentAccountID,
  eelist_object.value:AccountID AS eeListAccountID,
  allowance_object.value:AllowanceName
FROM
  new_raw_json,
  LATERAL FLATTEN (input => jsontext) outer_object,
  LATERAL FLATTEN (input => outer_object.value:content.EEList) eelist_object,
  LATERAL FLATTEN (input => eelist_object.value:AllowanceList) allowance_object;
```

Note that this only explodes one identified multi-value path (`List -> EEList -> AllowanceList`). It is unclear from the question if all the paths have to be exploded (such as `List -> EEList -> Addresses AND AllowanceList`) or if it is acceptable to store some of them as `VARIANT` (or other complex) type in the final result.

For example, if there is a need to to duplicate `AllowanceList` values for every listed address in `Addresses` under `EEList`, this could be achieved by performing a `JOIN` from two exploding query results (one that chains `List -> Addresses` and another that chains `List -> EEList -> AllowanceList`).

Comment: Thank you for your advice and direction, it's much appreciated!

Comment: @Harsh J, Can you give a look at my post? I am facing issue related to snowflake: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823080/how-to-run-snowflake-side-effect-functions-like-systemgenerate-scim-access-toke