# Can't query semi-structured data using lateral flatten etc

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, variant

I've got some data in a table, and one of the columns is a Variant which contains a ree of JSON data. I can successfully flatten arrays, and arrays within arrays to access data therein but I'm struggling with flattening key-value pairs to access the value for a given key.

I've seen the docs at https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial.html mapping this onto my use case results in NULL values in the results.

My variant is show in part below - In particular it's values like MatchStatus and the key/values under Variables that I'm interested in extracting.

Thanks for any helpful suggestions.

[image]

Comment: please share the original json with us

Comment: you can probably just query it with `variant_col:PricingRequest.MatchStatus`

Comment: Thanks both - Zephro provided the quick and annoyingly simple answer. I was over-thinking the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described JSON has a simple path-like structure with objects at various levels (and no arrays).

Per [Snowflake's semi-structured data documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#traversing-semi-structured-data), use the dot notation to extract a value following a (flatly nested) path:

```
Insert a colon : between the VARIANT column name
and any first-level element: <column>:<level1_element>.

Use dot notation to traverse a path in a JSON object:
<column>:<level1_element>.<level2_element>.<level3_element>.
```

An example would be (note the chained use of dots in the third and fourth lines):

```sql
SELECT
  badminton_odds:Id as id,
  badminton_odds:PricingRequest.MatchStatus as match_status,
  badminton_odds:PricingRequest.Variables.Dispersion as var_dispersion
FROM odds_table
```

You do not require [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) for simple, singular value extraction. Use FLATTEN when you have a need to explode some series data into multiple rows (such as in case of arrays).

For example, if the described JSON in the question is how a single array element looks in a long array of such objects, you may use FLATTEN to first break the whole array into rows, and then apply path style extraction to retrieve the value from each row.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, very helpful. Although the visible JSON is only objects, some of those objects contain arrays which contain might contain other arrays or objects, so you see how it gets complicated quickly and also where a FLATTEN is going to help.

Comment: You may also find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242195/9056819